# Pass Data from one activity to other activity and display on Listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pass-data

I Have 2 activities 1st one is Data activity there are some `Spinners` I would like to take data from that `spinner` and add them to the History activity and display to `ListView`. I don't want to open the second activity on `button` click. 
Bellow is what I have done till now.

I tried to find the similar questions but none was helpful.

**Data Activity :**

```
 public class Data extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);


    final Spinner handSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Arm_used);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> handAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hand));
    handAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    handSpiner.setAdapter(handAdapter);

    final Spinner weightSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_weight);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> weightAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weight));
    weightAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    weightSpiner.setAdapter(weightAdapter);



    final Spinner heightSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_height);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> heightAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.height));
    heightAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    heightSpiner.setAdapter(heightAdapter);


    final Spinner bloodTypeSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_blood_type);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> bloodTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bloodType));
    bloodTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bloodTypeSpiner.setAdapter(bloodTypeAdapter);


    final Spinner smallPressureSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_small_pressure);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> smallPressureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smallPressure));
    smallPressureAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    smallPressureSpiner.setAdapter(smallPressureAdapter);


    final Spinner bigPressureSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_big_pressure);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> bigPressureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Data.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bigPressure));
    bigPressureAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bigPressureSpiner.setAdapter(bigPressureAdapter);
}
```

**History Layout:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:text="Χέρι Αιμοδοσίας" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Αρτηριακή Πίεση" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Βάρος" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Ύψος" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Ομάδα Αίματος" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_Arm_used"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView15" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_weight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView17" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner_weight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView18" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_blood_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView14" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_small_pressure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner_big_pressure"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_big_pressure" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_big_pressure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnaddHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_small_pressure"
        android:text="Προσθήκη"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**History Layout:**

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: `I don't want to open the second activity on button click` then how do you want to open that activity??

Comment: take them from spinner to DB or Sharedprefernces ...when you visit the activity that you dont want to open....get them again

Comment: @abdulKawee From MainActivity I have buttons to lunch different activities.

Comment: In your question you wrote you dont want to open activity on button click

Comment: Sorry, I meant I don't want to open the 2nd activity from 1st activity AddButton click. I want only to add the data to the 2nd activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the data in a database and then retrieve them as mentioned or you can either directly pass the data from one activity to the other through the Intent starting the activity like so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(variable_name, content);
```

and then retrieve it from second activity

```
 String whatEver = getIntent().getExtras().getString(variable_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a model (POJO) class if you don't need your data to be persistent and then fetch data from the class while opening History activity.
If you need your data to be persistent, you can store it in a database or can use shared preference.